# What is the "-400", "-500" following the date in Time.now in ruby and is date compatible with postgres date field?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

Ruby and postgres question: I am wanting to insert the date from a Ruby script into a postgres database. 
The database date format is: `2013-03-13 17:08:51.207184-04` in postgres. BTW, what is "51.207184-04" in the date field in the Postgres database?

I want to write the data from ruby into the date column in postgres. I am assuming I need to use Time.now but I have no idea what that is? Whats up with the -400 or -500 at the end of the date time?

The postgres database field is: `timestamp without time zone NOT NULL`

Comment: I strongly suspect that "-0400" is a UTC offset of -4 hours. Please say *exactly* what the field type is in your database.

Comment: I guess ``51.207184`` are seconds + microseconds, ``-04`` is the timezone and ``-400``/``-500`` is the timezone expressed in another format..

Comment: I updated the above and gave the exact database field.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, the last bit is a timezone, expressed as hours relative to UTC.

I believe the PG timetamp shown is 2013-03-13 17h 08m 51.207184s at 4 hours behind UTC (but I'm not 100% familiar with postgres's field formats); in Ruby `-0400` on the end of `Time.now` means the same, and `-0500` means 5 hours behind.

Comment: To preserve your own sanity, it's usually best to store times without an offset, that is using UTC. Convert as required for display.

Answer (score 1):

the -400 or -500 refers to the timezone your script is running in, as an offset from UTC.

Refer to table 8.11 http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html